# Find the shortest Element, Should equal 0 when empty Array is entered but it doesn't

Tags: javascript

```
// Should equal 0 when an empty Array is entered

function getLengthOfShortestElement(arr) {

  
  var shortestElement = Infinity;
  
  for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].length < shortestElement) {
      shortestElement = arr[i].length;
    } else if (arr[i].length === 0) {
      return 0;
    } 
  }
  return shortestElement;
}

var output = getLengthOfShortestElement([]);
console.log(output);
```

Judging by the code why isn't it outputting 0? Instead it outputs Infinity..

Comment: The loop will never loop, as the loop condition is false from the very start. So, yes, you return Infinity.

Comment: People need to learn how to use a debugger, as early as possible. It would solve so many questions.

Comment: I don't know if getting 0 would be the best choice, because you can assume you have an empty list on the array and that is not true. You can use an specific value like the Infinite itself or -1. (using the Barmar solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array is empty, `shortestElement` is still `Infinity`, since the loop never runs and you don't reassign it.

You can simply check for an empty array at the beginning.

Another improvement is to initialize `shortestElement` from the first element, and then loop starting from the second element.

You should also check for a zero-length element before checking if the length is less than `shortestElement`, since `0` will always be less and you won't ever get to the `else if` (unless there are two zero-length elements in the array).

```js
function getLengthOfShortestElement(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  var shortestElement = arr[0].length;

  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length === 0) {
      return 0;
    } else if (arr[i].length < shortestElement) {
      shortestElement = arr[i].length;
    }
  }
  return shortestElement;
}

var output = getLengthOfShortestElement([]);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `arr.length === 0` outside of the loop, or else it will never run.
Try this instead

```
function getLengthOfShortestElement(arr) {

  
  var shortestElement = Infinity;
  
  for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].length < shortestElement) {
      shortestElement = arr[i].length;
    }
  }
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return shortestElement;
}

var output = getLengthOfShortestElement([]);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to accomplish what you're trying to do involves the `Array.reduce` method:

```js
function getLengthOfShortestElement(arr) {
  const toShortest = (shortest, { length: current }) => shortest < current ? shortest : current;
  const shortest = arr.reduce(toShortest, Infinity);
  return shortest === Infinity ? 0 : shortest;
}

console.log(
  getLengthOfShortestElement(['amazon', 'worm', 'lightyear']), // 4
  getLengthOfShortestElement([]) // 0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `arr.length == 0` when you pass an empty array, the `for` loop's condition will be false at the very start, and so the variable `shortestElement` will remain what it was initiliased to: `Infinity`.

However, if you would call the function with `[[]]` instead of `[]`, *then* you *do* have an empty array in your array, and you *will* get 0.

This shows there is a difference between an empty array and an array that has an empty array. Your function is designed to look at the arrays *inside* the array you pass. If there are none, it cannot say what is the *shortest* among those... that is truly undefined, so `Infinity` is not such a bad answer in that case.

Compare to what `Math.min` returns when you pass it no arguments at all:

```js
console.log(Math.min(3, 1)); // 1
console.log(Math.min(3)); // 3
console.log(Math.min()); // Infinity
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe it may be that you are checking arr[i].length instead of arr.length because you only check if arr[i].length is 0 and if then the function returns 0, otherwise shortestElement is still equal to infinity and is returned.

Comment: That check is correct, since it's checking the current element of the iteration. If the array is empty you never get there in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar What I meant was that because there is no check to see if the array length is 0, the shortestElement remains infinity and is returned. The individual element can be checked as well but the check for the array length is what I was referring to that could be done before the loop even begins.